# How to change the background colour of an image from black to transparent in PHP?

Tags: php, image

How to resize png and gif image and store transparent background using php?

This is my code

Your will resize the image to 200x200 px and climb to PIE dir. It's a good job. But when used with png or gif image (transparent bg). It will change bg to black. How can I make srote transparent bg after resizing the image?

**Original:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiGFt.jpg

**Copy:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHPDm.jpg

```
include 'compressImage.php';
    <?php
    $widthArray = array(200);
    foreach($widthArray as $newwidth)
    {                       
       compressImage($ext,$tmp,$path,$userID.$actual_image_name,$newwidth);
    }
    ?>
```

**compressImage.php:**

```
<?php
//Compress Image 
function compressImage($ext,$uploadedfile,$path,$actual_image_name,$newwidth)
{
    if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" )
    {
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
    }
    else if($ext=="png")
    {
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
    }
    else if($ext=="gif")
    {
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
    }
    else
    {
    $src = imagecreatefrombmp($uploadedfile);
    }
                                                                    
    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
    $filename = $path.$newwidth.'_'.$actual_image_name;
    imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    return $filename;
}
?>
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/94015/29516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the transparency you have to use an image format which allows transparency. See imagepng (http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagepng.php).